# Improving recommendation find nearst songs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I've trained my model, I want now to recommend songs for a given playlist! However, one issue that I encountered (see below) is that I need the embedding of that new playlist (as stored in my model) in order to find the closest relevant playlists in that embedding space using kmeans. I am not sure how to get around this issue- as is, it seems that I have to retrain my whole model each time I get an input playlist in order to get that playlist embedding. Therefore, I just test my model on a randomly chosen playlist (which happens to be rock and oldies, mostly!) from the training set.

To recommend songs, I first cluster the learned embeddings for all of the training playlists, and then select "neighbour" playlists for my given test playlist as all of the other playlists in that same cluster. I then take all of the tracks from these playlists and feed the test playlist embedding and these "neighboring" tracks into my model for prediction. This ranks the "neighboring" tracks by how likely they are (under my model) to occur next in the given test playlist.

This code is very slow. How could I improve this?

```
from keras.models import load_model
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

desired_user_id = 500
model_path = 'spotify_NCF_8_[64, 32, 16, 8].h5'
print('using model: %s' % model_path)
model = load_model(model_path)
print('Loaded model!')

mlp_user_embedding_weights = (next(iter(filter(lambda x: x.name == 'mlp_user_embedding', model.layers))).get_weights())

# get the latent embedding for your desired user
user_latent_matrix = mlp_user_embedding_weights[0]
one_user_vector = user_latent_matrix[desired_user_id,:]
one_user_vector = np.reshape(one_user_vector, (1,32))

print('\nPerforming kmeans to find the nearest users/playlists...')
# get 100 similar users
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=100, random_state=0, verbose=0).fit(user_latent_matrix)
desired_user_label = kmeans.predict(one_user_vector)
user_label = kmeans.labels_
neighbors = []
for user_id, user_label in enumerate(user_label):
    if user_label == desired_user_label:
        neighbors.append(user_id)
print('Found {0} neighbor users/playlists.'.format(len(neighbors))) 

tracks = []
for user_id in neighbors:
    tracks += list(df[df['pid'] == int(user_id)]['trackindex'])
print('Found {0} neighbor tracks from these users.'.format(len(tracks))) 

users = np.full(len(tracks), desired_user_id, dtype='int32')
items = np.array(tracks, dtype='int32')

print('\nRanking most likely tracks using the NeuMF model...')
# and predict tracks for my user
results = model.predict([users,items],batch_size=100, verbose=0) 
results = results.tolist()
print('Ranked the tracks!')
```

Comment: Couldn't you get around re-fitting by using distance search (i.e. kNN?)

Answer (score 0):

you should use kNN to find the neighbors. you can further improve the performance by using locality sensitive hashing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing.